# Java implementing MVC with SWT

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swt

### Mvc in Java SWT

Hello,
I'm very new to SWT and I interested in MVC pattern in Java with SWT. Ive tried to  separate models, controllers and views, but my controllers ara called in views, and i dont have any mids how to make transition between views. I didnt find any simple solution in the Internet.

Please suggest any docs, or maybe some patters which will help to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SWT then you should check out the Eclipse RCP framework version 4. It makes it much easier to use MVC in it. You can read about RCP 4 [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html). For the MVC part you can start [here](http://www.richclient2.de/2006_08_22/using-the-mvc-pattern-in-eclipse-applications/).

Answer (score 3):

[JFace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace) is a library built on top of SWT which contains a lot of widgets using MVC.

You can have a [look at the sources](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui) to see how they implement their models on top of SWT.

Comment: Yea, RCP uses JFace as well.

Comment: @ifma Thanks, fixed.